# What kind of patterns can I use in zsh parameter expansion?

Tags: regular-expression, zsh

In my zsh shell script I use `regexp-replace nname "_{2,}" "_"` successfully to reduce multiple "_"s to a single one, but when I try `${nname//_{2,}/'_'}` zsh doesn't seem to match the pattern.

`man zshexpn` is. not clear. It mentions globbing patterns but evidently other POSIX 1003.2 regular expressions such as in `${name//[^[:alnum:]]/"_"}`
 work OK in my script.

#### Motivation

I was looking for the parameter expansion equivalent of

```
regexp-replace nname "[^[:alnum:]]" "_"
regexp-replace nname "_{2,}" "_"
regexp-replace nname "_+$" ""
regexp-replace nname "^_+" ""
```

#### zsh

```
zsh --version
zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`${var//pattern/replacement}` is using zsh wildcard patterns for `pattern`, the same ones as used for *filename generation* aka globbing which are a superset of the `sh` wildcard patterns. The syntax is also affected by the `kshglob` and `extendedglob` options. The `${var//pattern/replacement}` comes from the Korn shell initially.

I'd recommend enabling `extendedglob` (`set -o extendedglob` in your `~/.zshrc`) which gives you the most features (more so than standard EREs) at the expense of some backward incompatibility in some corner cases.

You'll find it documented at `info zsh 'filename generation'`.

A cheat sheet for the mapping between ERE and extended zsh wildcards:

Standard `sh` ones:

- `.` -> `?`
- `.*` -> `*`
- `[...]` -> `[...]`

zsh extensions:

- `*` -> `#`
- `+` -> `##`
- `{x,y}` -> `(#cx,y)`
- `(...|...)` -> `(...|...)`

some  extra features not available in standard EREs:

- `^pattern` (negation)
- `x~y` (except)
- `<12-234>` match decimal number ranges
- `(#i)` case insensitive matching
- `(#a2)` approximate matching allowing up to 2 errors.
- many more

Whether wildcard patterns are anchored at start or end of the subject depends on what operator is used.

- Globs, `case` patterns, `[[ string = pattern ]]` and `${var:#pattern}` are anchored at both (`f*.txt` will match on `foo.txt`, not `Xfoo.txtY`)
- `${var#pattern}` and `${var##pattern}` are anchored at the start
- `${var%pattern)` and `${var%%pattern}` are anchored at the end
- `${var/pattern/repl}` and `${var//pattern/repl}` are not anchored but can be made so with `${var/#pattern}` (start) or `${var/%pattern}` (end).

`(#s)` and `(#e)` can also be used as the equivalents of `^`/`$` (ERE) or `\A`/`\z` (PCRE).

Whether repeating operators (`#`, `##`, `*`, `(#cx,y)`, `<x-y>`) are greedy depends on the operator as well (greedy with `##`, `%%`, `//`, `/` not with `#`, `%`), that can be changed with the `S` parameter expansion flag.

So for your examples:

- `regexp-replace nname "[^[:alnum:]]" "_"`: `${var//[^[:alnum:]]/_}`
- `regexp-replace nname "_{2,}" "_"`: `${var//_(#c2,)/_}`
- `regexp-replace nname "_+$" ""`: `${var%%_#}` or `${var/%_#}` (here using `#` for the `*` equivalent, you can use `##` for a `+` equivalent but that won't make any difference in this case).
- `regexp-replace nname "^_+" ""`: `${var##_#}` or `${var/#_#}`

Here, you could combine them with `${${${var//[^[:alnum:]]##/_}#_}%_}` (convert sequences of non-alnums to `_` and remove an eventual leading or trailing `_`).

Another approach could be to extract all the sequences of alnums and join them with `_`, using this hack:

```
words=()
: ${var//(#m)[[:alnum:]]##/${words[1+$#words]::=$MATCH}}
var=${(j:_:)words}
```

`regexp-replace` itself is an autoloadable function that calls `[[ $var =~ pattern ]]` in a loop. Note that as a result, [it doesn't work properly with the `^` anchor or word boundary or look-behind operators (if using the `rematchpcre` option)](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2019/msg01085.html):

```
$ a='aaab'; regexp-replace a '^a' x; echo "$a"
xxxb
$ a='abab'; regexp-replace a '\<ab' '<$MATCH>'; echo $a
<ab><ab>
```

(in the first example, `^a` is matched in turn against `aaab`, `aab`, `ab`, `b` in that loop).

Comment: Wow! What a fantastic answer. Thank you so much for taking the time to be so clear and comprehensive, Stéphane.

Comment: Well, very satisfying (if a little cryptic :-) solution: `${${${${name//[^[:alnum:]]/_}//_(#c2,)/_}/%_#}##_#}` equivalent to my four `regexp-replace` statements in OP. Note greedy form `${var/##_#}` required.

Comment: please note minor typo in answer. s/b `${var/##_#}` Regards!

Comment: @iainH, thanks. Fixed now. See also the edit for other approaches at doing it.

Comment: Solution `${${${var//[^[:alnum:]]##/_}#_}%_}` much more elegant now that `${var//[^[:alnum:]]##/_}` specifying that the longest instead of the  shortest non-album match should be replaced. Thanks again! Will enjoy unpacking your `words` function suggestion!