# Remove '?' character from many filenames in a single directory

Tags: rename, mv, delete

I have many files in a directory that have names containing `?`, and I want to remove these `?` characters.

Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Do the filenames contain the literal question mark character `?` or are they non-graphic characters being replaced by a question mark?

Comment: They contain a literal question mark character @Torin

Answer (score 0):

```
rename 's/\?//g' *
```

whould do the job to rename all the files

```
francois@zaphod:~/tmp$ ls
toto_?_  toto_?_1  toto_?_2

francois@zaphod:~/tmp$ rename 's/\?//g' *
francois@zaphod:~/tmp$ ls
toto__  toto__1  toto__2
francois@zaphod:~/tmp$
```

Comment: You might enjoy the tags on the question.

Comment: See updated question.

Comment: it doesn't work!

Comment: see new answer now with good question :)

Comment: The original `sed` command almost certainly did, unfortunately.  I hope that you have backups.  Note https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275254/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230/5132 for the now revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `bash` or any similar shell that knows how to replace all occurrences of a string matching a pattern in the value of a variable with `${variable//pattern/replacement}` (e.g. `zsh` or `ksh`):

```bash
for name in ./*'?'*; do
    mv -i "$name" "${name//'?'/}"
done
```

This is a short loop that iterates over all names in the current directory that contains at least one `?` (skipping hidden names).  For each such name, the `?` characters are removed from the filename and the result is used as the new filename of the file.

The single quotes around `?` in the patterns stops it from being treated as a the special globbing character that matches any single character (which is what an unquoted `?` does).  You could also have used either `\?` or `[?]`.

If the question marks that you see are from the output of `ls`, then they may represent non-printable characters.

To remove *these*, replace each `'?'` in the code above with `[![:print:]]`.  The `[![:print:]]` globbing pattern matches a character that is not printable.  The `[:print:]` character class is similar to `[:graph:]`, but the former matches the space character while the latter does not.  Using `[![:print:]]` would therefore *not* remove spaces, while using `[![:graph:]]` would remove spaces.

Comment: Z and Korn have it.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/557482/5132

Comment: @JdeBP Thanks, incorporated.